# highlighting one word by clicking on it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found a JQuery Script which allows you to highlight a word in a text by clicking on it.

Anyhow, is it possible to adapt the code that it is only possible to highlight one word by clicking on it? So, if the user clicks on a second word, the first color coded word would go back to normal.

```js
var words = $( "p" ).first().text().split( /\s+/ );
var text = words.join( "</span> <span>" );
$( "p" ).first().html( "<span>" + text + "</span>" );
$( "span" ).on( "click", function() {
$( this ).css( "background-color", "red" );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title>Click a word in the paragraph and highlight it.</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>
This domain is established to be used for illustrative examples in documents. You may use this domain in examples without prior coordination or asking for permission.
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately I cannot find the original source anymore from stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First call `$("span").css("background-color", "");` to reset the color of all `<span>`s before setting the color of the clicked element:

```js
var words = $("p").first().text().split(/\s+/);
var text = words.join("</span> <span>");
$("p").first().html("<span>" + text + "</span>");
$("span").on("click", function() {
  $("span").css("background-color", "");
  $(this).css("background-color", "red");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  This domain is established to be used for illustrative examples in documents. You may use this domain in examples without prior coordination or asking for permission.
</p>
```

You can also save the clicked element in a variable:

```js
var words = $("p").first().text().split(/\s+/);
var text = words.join("</span> <span>");
$("p").first().html("<span>" + text + "</span>");
let highlighted;
$("span").on("click", function() {
  $(highlighted).css("background-color", "");
  $(this).css("background-color", "red");
  highlighted = this;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  This domain is established to be used for illustrative examples in documents. You may use this domain in examples without prior coordination or asking for permission.
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for you help. However, I do not understand entirely what is saved in the variable "highlighted". I thought first the word which has been clicked on, but now I am not sure anymore. Maybe you can clarify that for me.

Comment: It stores the `this` from the last call, and the `this` inside a jQuery callback is the element the event is attached to. Here, that's one of the `<span>`s.

Answer (score 0):

in this case you can add `$( "span" ).css( "background-color", "white" );` in the onclick callback function this code will initialize all span's background color

```
<script>
var words = $( "p" ).first().text().split( /\s+/ );
var text = words.join( "</span> <span>" );
$( "p" ).first().html( "<span>" + text + "</span>" );
$( "span" ).on( "click", function() {
$( "span" ).css( "background-color", "white" );
$( this ).css( "background-color", "red" );
});
</script>
```